# Decompress using Winrar, and now I have no disk space?

Tags: windows-xp, disk-space, winrar

i have a hard drive, with 2 partitions.

drive C:, D:, and ofcourse my dvd-rom drive which is E:

i have a compressed file on my D: and its roughly 1.3 gigs, but when i try to decompress it to the same D: drive, it comes back and says I don't have enough space on my C: drive, and suddenly, i have 0bytes available.

i went to disk cleanup, cleared out my temp, but i only got 500megs out of that.

what the heck just happened?! ive never ever seen this before!

Answer (score 2):

WinRAR's temp directory is probably pointing at %TEMP% (which is likely on your C: drive).  Unfortunately I'm not on a Windows machine so I can't tell you the exact location to change this, but there should be an option in WinRAR's settings to configure the temp directory's location.

Comment: Select Options > Settings and then click on the Paths tab.  That'll point you to your temp folder.

Answer (score 2):

Open WinRAR, then go to Options->Settings (Ctrl+S). Switch to "Paths" tab, there you can change the path for "Folder for temporary files". I leave it blank, so that temporary files are created within current folder.